# How to run a 7zip batch without copying the batch file to the 7zip folder in c

Tags: batch-file, path, zip, 7zip

I have created a batch file to zip my backups, but the batch files works only if I copy the batch file to the 7zip.exe folder on c drive; otherwise it doesn't work . How do I run my batch file from any location?

Here is my command:

7z a -mhe -p1234 -t7z "D:\Batch test\2\%datetimef%.7z" "D:\Batch test\1*.*" -mx0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PATH %PATH%;"c:\7ZIP";
7z a -mhe -p1234 -t7z "D:\Batch test\2\%datetimef%.7z" "D:\Batch test\1*.*" -mx0
```

where the `c:\7zip` is the folder where 7zip is.

The problem is that your `7z.exe` is not in your [PATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) variable and cannot be found and executed.While when it is in the same directory it can be found and there is no problems with your execution.For script purposes you can edit the %PATH% variable with `PATH` command or edit it through environment variables .

Comment: Could you clarify your answer? Why would this command work, and why didn't the OP's command work?

Comment: There's a permanent way to set the %PATH% var: Setx PATH "C:\7ZIP;%PATH%;"

Answer (score 0):

You can put the full path to the 7z binary like so:

```
"c:\7zip"\7z a -mhe -p1234 -t7z "D:\Batch test\2\%datetimef%.7z" "D:\Batch test\1\*.*" -mx0
```

You're explicitly telling the interpreter where to look for the binary.